# Animation renders object for every single frame for entire animation

Tags: animation

I'm trying to create a simple rotation/translation animation with a cylinder and I end up with:

[image: Weird animation error]

When you press play, the mesh animates but the material preview is the same throughout each frame (as seen). It's the same if I render the animation...

Am I missing some setting somewhere?

Here is the blender file:

[image]

Blender v2.70

Comment: I want to know what you did there because thats a pretty interresting effect

Comment: please, if you can share the file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question pasting the provided link, and/or please add some  details about setup and blender version...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've enabled dupliframes (which duplicates it for every frame). Set duplication to None:
[image]

Comment: Damn dupliframes!  Thx @sdfgeoff